# passing null to setInterpolator crashes

Tags: android, animation, tween

I'm using TranslateAnimation object to animate my view. But it has a default ease-in & ease-out effect. I want no effects. Passing null to setInterpolator() method is making my application crash. What should i pass as an argument so that there are no effects? Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not pass `null` to `setInterPolator`. The default ('no effects') is a `LinearInterpolator`, which has a constant rate of change.

[Docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setInterpolator%28android.view.animation.Interpolator%29)

> *public void setInterpolator (Interpolator i)*
>
> Sets the acceleration curve for this animation.
>   Defaults to a linear interpolation.

Comment: Thanks!! <code>setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())</code> did the job!! Although it says that it defaults to linear interpolation but somehow it had acceleration effects. Anyways .. it works great now!!

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator)`